# SAP Table Control with button event

Tags: button, abap, dynpro

I have inserted button to table control, I am calling one more screen on the click of this button.

[image]

I need the line number of table control when I press this button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method;

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1581196

```
GET CURSOR LINE li_line.
```

This should return the line that triggered the push event.

Comment: [GET CURSOR - dynpro](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapget_cursor_dynpro.htm)